# Help with rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I seriously cant understand why this is so hard... I have some experience with other mvc frameworks but always heard rails was the easiest to code in.... right now I cant even get to my controller methods if i want to.

I used scaffold to creat 'student' which automatically created for me the controller, model and views for basic CRUD.. but now I just want to add a method "helloworld" to my controller and when i go to

```
http://localhost:3000/students/helloworld
```

I get a

> Couldn't find Student with ID=helloworld

error.

what am I missing?..  I know its got to do with routes and the REST thing but I still cant figure out then how else am I supposed to use my own methods... do I have to edit my routes.rb file everytime I create a new method?.. please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Routes for models in Rails are divided into 2 groups.  Ones that act on a single objects (think edit, update, delete) and ones that don't have a single object to act on (new, index).  If you want to create your own method that doesn't take an object ID you need to add a route config for that method in your routes file.  The methods are either member or collection methods.  Member methods URLs look like /model/id/method_name.  Collection methods look like what you want (/model/method_name).  Here is an example for your students model (routes.rb)

```
map.resources :students, :member => {:some_member_function_example => :get },
                           :collection => { :helloworld => :get }
```

Note: You can just remove the :member => ... from the config and only have collection if you have no member methods to define.

Comment: OK, so I have to be editing my routes.rb throughout the development... I hate that... I was used to just havning to edit routes if you wanted something fancy (in codeigniter)... the default was always controller/method/param1/param2/param3/param4, etc.
I have one more question.. I want to change the names of the methods the scaffold created.. cause my app is in spanish.
so for 'new' I want 'nueva', for 'create' I want 'crear'.....

Comment: I would look at the internationalization rails wiki for articles that can help you out.  http://rails-i18n.org/wiki

Answer (score 0):

Link `/students/foo` will not call the `foo` method of the `students_controller`. That's because REST mappings in Rails includes /`:controller/:id` route for GET. And your link matches this pattern.

In order to override that path (for methods with no parameters, like yours) use the following snippet:

```
map.resources :students, :collection => {:method_name => :get}
```